# Unity project have damaged every time and I can`t run it in Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am beginner in Unity and try to create my First Game.

Right now I try to write script that full my field by Hexs, that looks like this:

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HexManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _width, _height;

    [SerializeField] private float _Xstart, _Ystart, _Xstep, _Ystep, _shift;

    [SerializeField] private Hex _tilePrefab;

    [SerializeField] private Transform _cam;


    void Start()
    {
        GenerateGrid();
    }

    void GenerateGrid()
    {
        for (float y = _Ystart, i = 0; y > _Ystart - _height * _Ystep; y -= _Ystep, i++)
        {
            float shift = 0;
            if (i % 2 != 0) shift = _shift;

            for (float x = shift + _Xstart, j = 0; y < shift + _Xstart + _width * _Xstep; y += _Xstep, j++)
            {
                var spawnedTile = Instantiate(_tilePrefab, new Vector3(x, y), Quaternion.identity);
                spawnedTile.name = $"Hex {i} {j}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And every time, firstly my project closes, in few time. Then I try restart it and there is appeared message "it looks like another unity instance is running with this project open. Multiple Unity instances cant open the same project."

After that I already can't run my project, when I tap "Play" button, Editor just freeze and I can close it only with Task Manager. I've try to copy project, re-create it, but every time I bump into such error. And so about five times

Also I read on old forums that reason in Lockfile in Temp Folder, but I can't to delete it. Of course I can every time backup my project, but it will be too tiresome, if create big project

Comment: What are the values of your `[SerializeField]` variables? Its possible you are in an infinite (or just very large) loop

Comment: There usually int and float numbers. Moreover, this scripts can run and good work, but over time the project has crushed